# Why are requests with same url processed synchronously?

Tags: python, asynchronous, flask, request, cherrypy

I thought it was a quirk of the framework I was using, so I tested with another framework, but the result is the same: sending a burst of requests will process them asynchronously as expected when the urls are different, but will queue the requests with the same url and process them synchronously.

Why are some requests processed synchronously and some asynchronously?

Below the code to test with both Flask and CherryPy. Visiting `localhost:5000` with Flask and `localhost:8080` with CherryPy will load a page with JavaScript that will send a burst of 16 requests. The requests have an unused parameter in the query string which can have 4 different values, so the server will receive 4  different requests, each 4 times, for a total of 16 requests.

The server starts processing the first 4 requests for each parameter value, after finishing them will start processing the next 4 requests, etc.

Why aren't all 16 requests processed at the same time?

**Flask**

```
import flask
import time
import threading
import datetime

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

def log(txt):
    print('  {} {:6d} {}'.format(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f'), 
                              threading.current_thread().ident,
                              txt))

@app.route('/')
def index():
    log('index')
    return """<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script>
setTimeout(function(){{
  for(i=0; i<16; i++) {{
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", "test/" + i%4, true);
    xhttp.send();
  }}
}}, 2000);
</script>
</head>
<body>
hello
</body>
</html>"""

@app.route('/test/<x>')
def test(x):
    log('test{}'.format(x))
    time.sleep(3)
    log('   test{}'.format(x))
    return 'OK'

app.run(threaded=True)
```

**CherryPy**

```
import cherrypy
import time
import datetime
import threading

def log(txt):
    print('  {} {:6d} {}'.format(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f'), 
                              threading.current_thread().ident,
                              txt))

class Root:

    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        log('index')
        return """<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script>
setTimeout(function(){{
  for(i=0; i<16; i++) {{
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", "test?x=" + i%4, true);
    xhttp.send();
  }}
}}, 2000);
</script>
</head>
<body>
hello
</body>
</html>"""

    @cherrypy.expose
    def test(self, x):
        log('test{}'.format(x))
        time.sleep(3)
        log('   test{}'.format(x))
        return 'OK'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.quickstart(Root())
```

Comment: What is queueing the requests? Is it your browser/client? I would imagine it would queue them so it can used cached responses when possible.

Comment: @dirn I didn't think about investigating on the client side. I was testing with Chrome. I just tried with Firefox and there is no queuing. Thanks, this would be the answer.